# How to shrink ext4 partition using parted CLI?

Tags: partitioning, parted

I have microSD card with Ubuntu 20.10 for RaspberryPi 4. The microSD card is 32GB in size, however only about 2GB in total is being occupied on it. I would like to clone it onto 16GB microSD card and while I know how to successfully do it using GUI tools, I struggle with CLI.

The steps that I came up with so far are:

1. Power Off raspberry Pi
2. Remove SD card and insert into a computer running Ubuntu 20 (appears as /dev/sdb)
3. Check partitions using `parted -l` which shows that the partition I want to shrink has number `2`.
4. As partitions on this microSD card were automatically mounted on this OS, I unmount them all with `umount /dev/sdb1` and `umount /dev/sdb2`
5. I run file system check and let it complete using `e2fsck -f /dev/sdb2`
6. I shrink filesystem using `resize2fs /dev/sdb2 10G`
7. I shrink the partition using `parted /dev/sdb resizepart 2 10G`

At this point I open GParted just to visually verify my work and I am greeted with this error on partition /dev/sdb2 : [image: link]

If I now insert this microSD card to my RaspberryPi 4 it fails to boot and gets stuck on this screen: [image: link]

I am just playing around here so I'm not afraid to lose any data, I just want to learn how to properly shrink a partition of RaspberryPi microSD using CLI.

Comment: Note that the definition of `resizepart` is `resizepart NUMBER END`, i.e. the second number is where you want the partition to end, *not* the size of the partition

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I just figured it out myself. After step 7, there is a need for one more step:

8. After shrinking partition, extend filesystem to the limits of new partition by again running `resize2fs /dev/sdb2` without specifying new size.

Comment: Please accept your answer to close the question.
This was helpful but, I have a note: at step `6`, use a lower space value compare to `7` to avoid conflicts, you will get it back anyway on step `8`